# Selenium HowTo : Get url from an <a> tag that has no href attribute

Tags: java, javascript, url, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to get a link (that normally opens a new window on click) to open in the current window. My intent was to take the href attribute and just navigate to the url, but the link has no href attribute, it only has it's id and a class.

ex. `<a id="thisLink" class="linkOut">someLinkText</a>`

I only noticed when I tried to get the href attribute and received null. Is there a way to get the resulting url without opening the link or a way to open this link in the current window instead of a new one?

I'm testing the site through selenium webdriver and need to check the resulting page without opening it in a new window.

Comment: How does your anchor tag know what url to open if there isn't a `href`?

Comment: The "link" in this case is `current-page-url#thisLink`

Comment: That's the question to asK...

Comment: If it's opening a new page then some javascript is intercepting the click and substituting a link.

Comment: Well if it's the current-page-url... you know it right ? and if there's an href, you can retrieve it. If you want to keep the anchor, just append the #id to the current-url then?

Comment: An anchor element without an href is an anchor definition, not a link. Something you can link *to*. If someone has turned that anchor definition into a link using JavaScript, they're doing it wrong. :)

Comment: they had a few things to make occur when a link out is clicked. So then is there a way to get the url without executing the javascript, or a way to force the javascript to open withing the current window instead?

Comment: I would recommend changing the title of your question to something more "selenium".

Comment: It is not my code, mine is the test for it. I'll change the title

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you intend to do with a `known-url#id` url ? If you dont have a specific need, you can just keep known-url...

Anyway, for redirecting you can use `window.location.href = new-url`. And to get the url, you either take the href or build the url yourself with the id of the anchor.

**-- Edit --**
I see your last update of your question's description... it seems this is much more a selenium "howto" question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I only had that in the tags and then it was removed. I put it back and will change the title

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a click event on that anchor which opens the new page. Look for it in any javascript code, it most likely finds the anchor with the id so try looking for that.

If you have jQuery try seeing it like this `$._data($("#thisLink")[0], "events" ).click;`

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening:

```
var link = document.getElementById('thisLink');

link.onclick = function() {
    window.open('https://www.google.com');
};
```

What you are wanting to happen:

```
var link = document.getElementById('thisLink');

link.onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
};
```

You need to find where the `onclick` handler is for your anchor tag and if it is using `window.open` you need to replace it with `window.location.href`.

Comment: Yes, if this happens in his own code, it's easy. Since he is testing a website with selenium, he won't be able to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the option of modifying the original code. I am only testing it